why gitlab-runner can't create cache directory?
on my server with gitlab runner I have a directory /home/gitlab-runner/cache

but when I run the pipeline I see this error:
Saving cache for successful job
00:01
Creating cache 0_package-lock-dffda08a93effdc70d8ae70cedfddb00acf95b92-non_protected...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=3081411 revision=b72e108d version=16.1.0
node_modules/: found 62066 matching artifact files and directories 
FATAL: mkdir ../../../../../cache: permission denied 
Failed to create cache
Creating cache install-non_protected...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=3081457 revision=b72e108d version=16.1.0
.npm/: found 5626 matching artifact files and directories 
FATAL: mkdir ../../../../../cache: permission denied 
Failed to create cache
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded

my pipeline:
default:
  cache:
    # most npm libraries will only have 1 entry for the base project deps
    - &global_cache_node_mods
      key:
        files:
          - package-lock.json
      paths:
        - node_modules/
      policy: pull # prevent subsequent jobs from modifying cache
  tags:
    - frontend

install:
  image: ...
  stage: .pre # always first, no matter if it is listed in stages
  cache:
    # Mimic &global_cache_node_mods config but override policy
    # to allow this job to update the cache at the end of the job
    # and only update if it was a successful job (#5)
    - <<: *global_cache_node_mods
      when: on_success
      policy: pull-push

    # store npm cache for all branches (stores download pkg.tar.gz's)
    # will not be necessary for any other job
    - key:
        ${CI_JOB_NAME}
        # must be inside $CI_PROJECT_DIR for gitlab-runner caching (#3)
      paths:
        - .npm
      when: on_success
      policy: pull-push
  script:
    # define cache dir & use it npm!
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline

If the cache directory exists, why did the "Permission Denied" exception occur?

readlink -f ../../../../../cache and check that directory and readlink -f ../../../../../ directory permissions

I see that directory isn't /home/gitlab-runner, $ readlink -f ../../../../../cache
/data/cache
$ readlink -f ../../../../../
/data
